# Calculating PLT's virtual address using sh_addr

Tags: linux, elf

Is it possible to calculate the virtual address in memory where the .plt section will be loaded if I know the sh_addr of .plt? What base address do I need to add to it to get to the address?

**EDIT 5 Jan 2024**

Sorry for the confusion, let me explain the problem I am trying to solve.

If some code can tamper with the PLT or GOT of a loaded shared library in the process memory (perform hooking), how can we detect it? I was thinking if I could somehow find the PLT or GOT of a shared library by parsing the ELF file in memory.

However, articles I read are about parsing an ELF file on disk so I wondered if I was able to parse the ELF file on disk and find the sh_addr of PLT or GOT sections then whether I can use the value in sh_addr to add to a base address in memory and find the PLT or GOT in memory.

From there I want to inspect the opcodes in PLT to see if they are modified. If its the GOT, then I want to inspect the address and see whether it leads to some function within an unknown library.

As for why do I think that there is some code tampering with the shared library's PLT or GOT, I don't have an answer. I am actually trying to find out if indeed that is the case or rule out the possibility.

Comment: Your question is exceedingly unclear. The answer is: "yes, you need to add appropriate relocation", but what is appropriate relocation depends on what you are actually doing. http://xyproblem.info may be relevant here.

Comment: Sorry about that, let me see if I am able to add more context to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to calculate the virtual address in memory where the .plt section will be loaded if I know the sh_addr of .plt?

Yes, and you don't even need the `sh_addr` -- all the structures needed to find `.plt` and `.got` are already in memory, you don't need to parse anything on disk.

Start by locating `struct link_map *map` in memory by calling `dlopen(RTLD_DEFAULT, RTLD_LAZY)`. That `map` gives you a linked list of all ELF images loaded into memory, and access to each image's dynamic section via `.l_ld` entry.

In each dynamic section you'll want to find entries with `.d_tag == DT_PLTGOT`, then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970433/50617) to iterate over the `.got.plt` entries.

Note however that if your process has been tampered with, the loader in-memory structures may have been corrupted as well, and you may crash trying to access them.

> If some code can tamper with the PLT or GOT of a loaded shared library in the process memory (perform hooking), how can we detect it?

The best way is to link your binaries with `-Wl,-z,now,-z,relro` flags. These flags ask the runtime loader to resolve all `.plt` references at load time and to use `mprotect` to make `.got` read-only afterwards.

That makes hijacking the `.got` entries after the program has started much harder (though not impossible).

Comment: Thanks @Employed Russian. I should have been more specific that I was asking this question in relation to Linux and Android and it seems that dlinfo and dladdr1 are not in Android. I will ask another one about dlinfo and dladdr1.